# Datestamp for modified cells in googlesheet

Tags: javascript

I have a sheet that I used to share among my colleagues to get the record from them. From the table below, they will feedback their input to D1,E1 and F1. Is that any script I can use to note down the timing as long as those cells (D1-F1) are modified. D1->G1, E1-H1, F1-I1. Please help, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hi Carr, the code work fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the onEdit() trigger

```
function onEdit(e){
  var currentTime = new Date();
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 4) { // D corresponds to fourth 
    e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(currentTime);
  }
  // ... other case
}
```

Event object is well documented on [this official doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), available API about [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()).